# How can I scale the y axis?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a file I import and read into a table of $2 \times n$. I can plot this data using the following code:

```
directory = "c:\nameofdirectory";
SetDirectory[directory];
filenames = FileNames[];
readlist = ToString[filenames[[1]]];
table = OpenRead[readlist];
data = ReadList[table, {Number, Number}];
Close[table];

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Joined -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Voltage (V)", "Current (A)"}];
```

but the $y$-axis is order of $10^{-6} A$. I'd prefer to have my $y$-data scaled by $10^{-6}$ then label my axis is `microA` instead of `A`. I've tried using `Ticks` but I don't really understand how that works (it never changes my plot at all when I use it).

If there's no easy way to do this, can someone tell me how to directly divide my $y$-values from the input? I can separate the $y$-values from "data" and divide them using

```
xdat = List[];
ydat = List[];
For[j = 1, j < Length[data] + 1, j++,
    AppendTo[xdat, data[[j]][[1]]];
    AppendTo[ydat, data[[j]][[2]]];
   ];

y=ydat/10^-6;
```

but I don't know how to place them back into the form as before so that it can be easily plotted with `ListPlot`.

Comment: Welcome at Mathematica SE! You should try to simplify your post to provide minimal working example which reproduces Your issue. Have a look how to format a post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of ways. For example:

```
data = Table[{x, 10^-6  Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];
ListPlot[data /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 10^6 y}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {All, All}, Joined -> True, 
        FrameLabel -> {"Voltage (V)", "Current (Ma)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks so much! that is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @issk2q when using named patterns in a replacement rule use `RuleDelayed` (short form `:>`) unless you specifically know otherwise.  It will save you headache.

Answer (score 5):

belisarius showed replacement rules.  I favor [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) or [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) for such operations.  For large data [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) will be of use.  Finally I was remiss not to mention the Dot operator in my original answer.  Here are some examples, borrowing belisarius's data source.

First I create a larger data set so that performance differences are apparent:

```
data = {#, 1*^-6 Sin@#}\[Transpose] & @ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.00001];
```

This uses the listability of `Sin` for greater performance, much as I will show below.

You can use `Apply` at level one, shorthand `@@@` for a concise operation:

```
data1 = {#, 1*^6 #2} & @@@ data; // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.359
> ```

`Map` is a bit more efficient because it does not unpack the array:

```
data2 = {#[[1]], 1*^6 #[[2]]} & /@ data; // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.156
> ```

An orders of magnitude faster than either method above is to transpose the data, scale it using listable functions, and transpose again to put it back in the original form:

```
data3 = {#, 1*^6 #2}\[Transpose] & @@ (data\[Transpose]); // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.015
> ```

(See [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/Transpose.html) for `\[Transpose]`.)

Equally fast for this particular task is the `Dot` operator:

```
data = data.{{1, 0}, {0, 1*^6}}; // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.015
> ```

It is not as flexible as the transpose method however, as that method can work with any scaling method and not merely simple multiplication.

The operations are equivalent:

```
data1 === data2 === data3 === data4
```

> ```
> True
> ```