# How to create a mirror-symmetrical list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

My data file can be found here: [data](http://www.mediafire.com/download/tk1d151ueou52gn/mnl.out)

```
data = Import["mnl.out", "Table"];
```

First we remove the headers

```
l0 = SplitBy[data, Dimensions][[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

and then we plot it

```
L1 = ListPlot[l0, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{6., 13}, {-0.9, 2.4}}]
```

[image]

Now I want to create a new list `l1` (with the same structure as `l0`) so as the corresponding plot (in green) to be mirror-symmetrical with respect to the `y = 0` axis.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [(38138)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38138/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like I must be missing something but this *seems* to answer your question:

```
new = Map[{1, -1} # &, l0, {-2}];

ListLinePlot[new, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 PlotRange -> {{6., 13}, {-2.4, 0.9}}]
```

[image]

Since it seems that this is indeed what you want here is a faster but to me more opaque method using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html):

```
new2 = l0.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}};

new == new2   (* True *)
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I tried `l1 = Table[{l0[[i, j]][[1]], -l0[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, 
   Length[l0]}, {j, 1, Length[l0]}]` but the new list has less points. Any idea why?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z You would need to change the second iterator to `{j, 1, Length @ First @ l0}`.

Comment: "more opaque" - unless you go with the "matrix multiplication" viewpoint. Then, a diagonal matrix is easily interpreted as a scaling transform. Here's the equivalent, but maybe cognitively less demanding version: `ScalingTransform[{1, -1}] /@ l0`.

Comment: @J.M.  Good to have you back! :-)  I am not surprised the dot operation is transparent to you but I have yet to reach that level of familiarity with matrix operations.

Answer (score 5):

Just for trivial variety illustrating `MapAt` and using dummy data (as well as my original version which is not meaningfully different from Mr Wizard: whose answer I have upvoted):

```
dat = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, #] & /@ RandomReal[1, {3, 10}];
f = {1, -1} # &
ListPlot[Map[f, dat, {2}]~Join~dat, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

now using `MapAt`:

```
ListPlot[MapAt[-# &, dat, {All, All, 2}]~Join~dat, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
reflectF = GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]] &;

Show[L1, L1 /. l_Line :> {Green, reflectF @ l}, PlotRange -> {{6., 13}, All}]
```

[image]

```
l1 = ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}] /@ l0;
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> {Green}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{6., 13}, {-2.4, 0.9}}]
```

[image]